# Setting tab order of item on the dialog

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am facing a problem in setting the tab order in a dialog box. To set the tab order I have used the function SetWindowPos().

Initially it will be focused to one of the dialog item, but if I press tab it will not change the focus to the other items on the dialog box.

Please help he to fix the problem. 
bellow is the code...

```
HWND hBtn1 = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_OPEN);

HWND hBtn2 = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_CLOSE);
HWND hBtn3 = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_SAVE);

bool result = ::SetWindowPos(hBtn1, hBtn2, 0, 0, 0, 0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
result = ::SetWindowPos(hBtn2, hBtn3, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really have to set the tab order by code? 
Just press Ctrl+D in the dialog designer!

Update:
Using `SetWindowPos` won't help you. The parameter that you think it will define the taborder just sets the z-order, meaning the order how controls are painted if they overlap. I'm not sure, but I think the tab-order is defined by the order how the controls are created.

Next update:
A possible workaround is to watch the keyboard-events for the Tab-key, then get the active control and set the focus to the control which should come next.

Comment: i searched in the net to set the tab order but most of them told to use SetWindowPos(). i their any way to set the tab order Programatically.

Comment: IsDialogMessage implements tabbing. Its logic is to call hwnd = GetWindow( hwnd, GW_NEXT ); starting with the current focus control HWND in a loop until it finds a child window with the WS_TABSTOP style.

Comment: But I think that the call to GetWindow(hwnd,GW_NEXT) is the same as NextDlgCtrl() and you can't change the tab-order at runtime.

Comment: *"[The tab order follows the Z-order.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030826-00/?p=42793)"*.