# Change Tab order by code in a MFC Dialog

Tags: mfc, tabs

I created a control by code in the OnInitDialog, but i cannot find any way to change the tab order of the dialog by code.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812880/setting-tab-order-of-item-on-the-dialog

Comment: ...except that the duplicate's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tab order of controls on a dialog is governed by the Z-Order of those controls. So, to change the tab order, change the z-order positioning of the relevant controls.

You can change the z-order by using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: The example link now links to something wrong, I think.

Comment: I removed the misdirected link. It was correct ~12 years ago :)

Answer (score 21):

---

**First Option**

use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on resource view in visual studio. and change tab order

---

**Other option**

An easier solution is **change the sequence of controls** in **.rc** file...that will change your tab order and z order both.

For Eg.
this dialog will have Tab Order `IDOK` first, then `IDCANCEL`

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "My About Box"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK",IDOK,174,18,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,174,35,50,14
END
```

now if you change it to

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "My About Box"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,174,35,50,14
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK",IDOK,174,18,50,14
END
```

This will have Tab Order `IDCANCEL` first then `IDOK`

Comment: For, first options you have to start from 1 and set for all. I prefer the second option.

Comment: @Sarker No, you don't. There is a HOTKEY you can press so that when you click a control is starts re-numbering from that control onwards and leaves the others alone.

Comment: @Sarker I think it is CTRL + SHIFT and click on the control that stays the same number. Then each control after is re-numbered.