# MFC: dynamically created CEdit is not animated and does not change the appearance

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

Does anyone know why my dynamically created CEdit is not animated like a CEdit control created in the dialog editor?

When hovering with the cursor over the control, the color of the frame does not change (*In normal case the gray color changes slightly*) - When Selected, the color of the frame does not change either (*should be blue*).

```
CRect staticEditRect = CRect();
m_ctrlEditStatic.GetWindowRect(&staticEditRect);
ScreenToClient(&staticEditRect);

// offset position
CONST INT defaultPosVertSpace = 7;
staticEditRect.OffsetRect(0, staticEditRect.Height() + defaultPosVertSpace);

// create dynamic Edit 
CEdit* ctrlEditDynamic = new CEdit;
ctrlEditDynamic->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER, staticEditRect, this, IDC_EDIT_NEW_DYNAMIC);
ctrlEditDynamic->SetFont(m_ctrlEditStatic.GetFont());
```

Here is an example of what it usually looks like:
[Blue border while focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIFzt.png)

And here is a screenshot of what my CEdit Control looks like:
[My CEdit control (Nothing happend)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NguPE.png)

My goal was to add, depending on the case, dynamic CEdit controls that look exactly like the original (say size, appearance, behavior...). I have already tried a few things, but can't find the damn reason.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you [enabled Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)?

Comment: maybe this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995885/mfc-how-to-set-the-focus-of-cedit-boxes

Comment: @IInspectable Do I need this?  

The other control is also without "in style".
Besides, I only want the default style and it is not a custom control. 

Is there a simple function with which I can set/activate the default "visual style"?

Thanks

Comment: I just provided you with a link that explains how to enable the default visual style, that was introduced in Windows Vista.